# Word that means "continuing the current thought"

Tags: single-word-requests

The precise word eludes me, but I remember that it appeared in the context of a sentence similar to this one:

> That is a valid choice, but in making it, you will create unintended side-effects; _________, you will need to choose wisely.

I am sure it is **not** any of these three words/phrases:

> - consequently
> - as well
> - furthermore

Comment: Hello, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I made some minor wording and formatting changes to your question to make its meaning (as I understand it) a bit clearer. If the changes have  not improved the question, in your opinion, you can easily roll the edited version back to your original wording. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*[Therefore](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/therefore)*:

> adverb
>
> For that reason; consequently:
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 0):

**"Accordingly"** would work as well, although you may dislike having two words ending in -ly. The same objection of euphony applies to your own "consequently", which you are rejecting, although otherwise it seems to me perfectly okay in that blank.